# REACT NATIVE: fetching array of image from firestore database collection to carousel

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

Good day.
I have managed to fetch an array of images from firestore database collection, the only problem is that it seems that I cannot loop over the array that I am retrieving from the database.
I  need to dynamically display my images on the carousel.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { SwiperFlatList } from 'react-native-swiper-flatlist';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { white } from 'react-native-paper/lib/typescript/styles/colors';
import { color } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Carousel from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel';


//const colors = ["tomato", "thistle", "skyblue", "teal"];

const names = [{"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2FJB.png?alt=media&token=377f1629-6807-4343-b826-93d1c2bc5de6"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2Fgymtarp.png?alt=media&token=b2d1c923-2b5c-4066-bf8f-dc12de399059"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fb75d0848-b37f-4584-ab46-f355ca838e83.jpg?alt=media&token=adaa8559-de91-4ced-b056-84300123102e"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2FSANDO.png?alt=media&token=274c946b-7f20-4c07-8545-431a0558257c"}];

const App = () => {
  const [ads, setAds] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of ads

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('AdsDB')
      //.orderBy('Menu', 'asc')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        //const ads = [];
        /*
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
          ads.push({
            ...documentSnapshot.data(),
            key: documentSnapshot.id,
          });
        });
        */
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const { AdImage } = doc.data();
          ads.push({
            //id: doc.id,
            AdImage,
            //Price,
          });
        });
        setAds(ads);
        console.log(ads);

        //console.log(Object.entries(ads));
      });
  
    // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
    return () => subscriber();
    }, []);

return (

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SwiperFlatList
      autoplay
      autoplayDelay={2}
      autoplayLoop
      index={2}
      showPagination
      data={ads}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={[styles.child, { backgroundColor: item }]}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{item.AdImage}</Text>
          <Image
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                 height: "30%",
              position: 'absolute',
              top:0,
                alignItems: 'center', 
                justifyContent: 'center'}}
                source={{uri : item.AdImage}}
              resizeMode={'stretch'} // cover or contain its upto you view look
              />
        </View>
      )}
    />
  </View>
)
};

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', },
  child: { width, justifyContent: 'center', height: '100%' },
  text: { fontSize: width * 0.1, textAlign: 'center' },
});

export default App;
```

Thank you for answering my question. Mabuhay! I'm from the Philippines.

Comment: I would recommend you to add { } to the render item function and console.log the items, you'll probably get a clue of what's happening. Please share the output and I'll try to help you further. 

Initially all seemed correctly placed.

Comment: Additionally, you should return an "empty state" message when the array is empty probably, instead of the full carrousel

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, Sir. You mean this part of my code?  renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={[styles.child, { backgroundColor: item }]}>.........

Comment: Sorry for the late response I am asleep when you comment on my question

Comment: Sir, I did what you told me. I declared a {console.log(item)} Unfortunately, it gives me output with a single image link, I expected 6 image links.

Comment: Is item an array? Or what type of data structure at the moment of console logging?

Comment: Hi, Sir as of now this is the output.

LOG  {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2FJB.png?alt=media&token=377f1629-6807-4343-b826-93d1c2bc5de6"}

Comment: My expected output is.


LOG  [{"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2FJB.png?alt=media&token=377f1629-6807-4343-b826-93d1c2bc5de6"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2FbornRich.png?alt=media&token=96f3fb9a-2355-4f77-8611-89f585bbb3ca"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2Fgymtarp.png?alt=media&token=b2d1c923-2b5c-4066-bf8f-dc12de399059"},......so forth

Comment: Did you try the solution by chance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I am seeing is that probably meanwhile you are receiving asynchronously the snapshots, the setState did not ended running (a race condition between the velocity receiving snapshots and the exact time needed to persist the state)

I would try to delay the state change and use the previous state value in the setter, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {.   
    const subscriber = firestore()
    .collection('AdsDB')
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const { AdImage } = doc.data();
          setTimeout(() => {
            setAds((prevAds) => [...prevAds, AdImage]);
          }, 500);
  
        });
  console.log(ads);
  //console.log(Object.entries(adsFromFirebase));
});
```

Comment: Hello there Sir. I'm sorry for the late response. I'm a bit busy these past few days. I tried your solutions but unfortunately, the image is not appearing though it gives me a continuous output from the firestore database.

Comment: What is the output of the ads stored in the state from the body of the component?

Answer (score 0):

These are my code, Sir. It gives an empty array.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
    import { Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';
    import { SwiperFlatList } from 'react-native-swiper-flatlist';
    import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
    import { white } from 'react-native-paper/lib/typescript/styles/colors';
    import { color } from 'react-native-reanimated';
    
    
    
    
    const colors = ["tomato", "thistle", "skyblue", "teal"];
    
    const names = [{"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2FJB.png?alt=media&token=377f1629-6807-4343-b826-93d1c2bc5de6"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2Fgymtarp.png?alt=media&token=b2d1c923-2b5c-4066-bf8f-dc12de399059"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fb75d0848-b37f-4584-ab46-f355ca838e83.jpg?alt=media&token=adaa8559-de91-4ced-b056-84300123102e"}, {"AdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pindot-65e7c.appspot.com/o/Ads%2FSANDO.png?alt=media&token=274c946b-7f20-4c07-8545-431a0558257c"}];
    
    const App = () => {
      const [ads, setAds] = useState([]); // Initial empty array of ads
    
    
      useEffect(() => {   
        const subscriber = firestore()
        .collection('AdsDB')
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              const { AdImage } = doc.data();
              setTimeout(() => {
                setAds((prevAds) => [...prevAds, AdImage]);
              }, 500);
      
            });
      console.log(ads);
      //console.log(Object.entries(adsFromFirebase));
      });
        
      // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
      return () => subscriber();
      }, []);
    
      /*
      useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = firestore()
          .collection('AdsDB')
          //.orderBy('Menu', 'asc')
          .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            //const ads = [];
            /*
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
              ads.push({
                ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                key: documentSnapshot.id,
              });
            });
            
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              const { AdImage } = doc.data();
              ads.push({
                //id: doc.id,
                AdImage,
                //Price,
              });
            });
            setAds(ads);
            //console.log(ads);
    
            //console.log(Object.entries(ads));
          });
      
        // Unsubscribe from events when no longer in use
        return () => subscriber();
        }, []);
    */
    
    return (
    
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SwiperFlatList
          autoplay
          autoplayDelay={2}
          autoplayLoop
          index={2}
          data={ads}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={[styles.child, { backgroundColor: item.colors }]}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{item.AdImage}</Text>
              
              <Image
                  style={{
                    width: "100%",
                     height: "30%",
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top:0,
                    alignItems: 'center', 
                    justifyContent: 'center'}}
                    source={{uri : item.AdImage}}
                  resizeMode={'stretch'} // cover or contain its upto you view look
                  />
                  {/*}*/}
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    )
    };
    
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', },
      child: { width, justifyContent: 'center', height: '100%' },
      text: { fontSize: width * 0.1, textAlign: 'center' },
    });

 export default App;
```

This is the output.
LOG  Running "myApp" with {"rootTag":21}
LOG  []